# I have tears because I don't know how to field initialize a Dictionary with Action?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

In Unity projects featuring explosions you often do this

```
private Dictionary<string, System.Action> explosions;

void .. initialize in your class constructor .. ()
    {
    explosions = new Dictionary<string, System.Action>();
    explosions.Add("huge", SomeCall);
    explosions.Add("huger", SomeCall);
    etc
    }
```

No problem, but it would make me happy if you could do this...

```
private Dictionary<string, System.Action> explosions =
    new Dictionary<string, System.Action>()
    {
    {"huge", SomeCall},
    {"huge", SomeCall},
    etc
    };
```

That would make me much happier ... you know that feeling when you sleep better, enjoy meals with more of a smile?

Of course, that doesn't work because:

> Assets/scripts/objects/flite groups/ReallyTremendousExplosions.cs(134,26): error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `ReallyTremendousExplosions.SomeCall()'

Can anyone bring me peace on this?

Is there a way to get around the fact that you have to do it at initialization time?

Comment: Less drama would be appropriate ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `SomeCall` is a *non static* method and that's why you can't use it in the *field initializer*. However you can put the initialization into *constructor*:

```
  public class MyClass {
    ...
    // non static method
    private void SomeCall() { ... }

    private Dictionary<string, System.Action> explosions;

    public MyClass() {
      explosions = new Dictionary<string, System.Action>() {
        {"huge", SomeCall},
        {"huger", SomeCall},
      };
    }
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Hi Dimitry - yes, **that's exactly what I did**.  (In the code example `prep` (preparation) is obviously a initializer.)  I want to know if there's a way to **get around that and do a field initialization!**  Perhaps using a .. delegate, or something?  It makes me very said I have to initialize in the constructor  :/

Comment: @Joe Blow: No there's no such a way; in *.Net* (unlike *Java*) you can't reference non-static fields/methods/properties... in a field initializer.

Answer (score 3):

I love dictionary initializers and I use them all the time. I feel your tears.

The answer is in your question, use a delegate!

```
public class ReallyTremendousExplosions
    {
        private delegate void ExplosionFactory(ReallyTremendousExplosions source);

        private Dictionary<string, ExplosionFactory> Explosions = new Dictionary<string, ExplosionFactory>()
        {
            { "huge", x => x.SomeMethod() },
            { "huger", x => x.SomeMethod() }
        };

        private void SomeMethod()
        {
              //Render massive explosions...
        }

        public void RenderNamedExplosion(string explosionName) {
            ExplosionsFactory explosionFactory;
            if (!Explosions.TryGet(explosionName, out explosionFactory) {
                    throw new NoSuchExplosionException(explosionName);
            }

            explosionFactory(this);
        }
    }
```

Code *fully tested* in Unity5/Mono.

Comment: Holy Explosions.  Just you wait until I try this out!  "OMGC#"

Comment: That actually works. You dont' really need the delegate declaration tho, you could pass Action<ClassType>. Note that it requires to pass the calling object dict[str](this);

Comment: @fafase what syntax do you mean there buddy?

Comment: public Dictionary<string, Action< ReallyTremendousExplosions >> Explosions; , that is the only difference. The rest remains the same.